An inequality and two limits for series
In Corollary 2 of the paper [1] below, Qi and his coauthors derived the inequality
\begin{equation}\label{log-exp-last-proof-ineq}\tag{EI}
\Biggl[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+2}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}\Biggr] \Bigg[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}\Biggr] \ge\Biggl[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+1}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}\Biggr]^2
\end{equation}
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $u\in(-\infty,\infty)$. Similarly, we pose the following problem.
Problem 1. The inequality
\begin{equation}\label{log-exp-last-inverse-ineq}\tag{FI}
\Biggl[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+2}{n+1}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}\Biggr] \Biggl[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}\Biggr]
\le\Biggl[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+1}{n+1}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}\Biggr] \Biggl[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+1}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}\Biggr]
\end{equation}
is sound for $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
When $u>0$, the inequality \eqref{log-exp-last-inverse-ineq} has been proved for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
When $u<0$, the inequality \eqref{log-exp-last-inverse-ineq} has not been proved yet.
Could you please give a proof of the inequality \eqref{log-exp-last-inverse-ineq} for $u<0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
Problem 2. The inequality \eqref{log-exp-last-proof-ineq} is equivalent to
\begin{equation}\label{log-exp-last-equiv}\tag{GI}
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+1}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}} {\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}}
\le\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+k+1}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}} {\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+k}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}}
\to???, \quad k\to\infty
\end{equation}
for $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $u\in(-\infty,\infty)$.
Problem 3. The inequality \eqref{log-exp-last-inverse-ineq} can be reformulated as
\begin{equation}\label{log-exp-last-inv-ineq}\tag{HI}
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+1}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}} {\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n}{n}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}}
\ge\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+k+1}{n+k}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}} {\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{j+n+k}{n+k}}\frac{u^{j}}{j!}}
\to???,\quad k\to\infty
\end{equation}
for $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Reference

Zhi-Hua Bao, Ravi Prakash Agarwal, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, Some properties on normalized tails of Maclaurin power series expansion of exponential function, Symmetry 16 (2024), no. 8, Article 989, 15 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym16080989.


When $u>0$, the inequality (FI) for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in Problem 1 has been proved in Remark 5 of the paper: Feng Qi, Absolute monotonicity of normalized tail of power series expansion of exponential function, Mathematics Vol. 12 (2024), no. 18, Article 2859, 11 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/math12182859 or https://www.researchgate.net/publication/383999684.
